# Statistics of time series of discrete events

Tags: statistics

I have many series of discrete events with respect to some origin. E.g.

```
-5s, -4s, -1s, 2s, 3s
```

would be one such series with the first event 5 seconds before the origin, and the last event 3 seconds after it, with 5 events occurring.

What are the approaches to analyse many such series? What kind of characteristic values would normally be used to classify them? How can one cluster them into similar series (and what are even good measurements of similarity)?

I would assume that analysis of such series is nothing new, but I don't know the proper name for these kind of series ("discrete event series", "discrete time series" etc. didn't turn anything up when googling, there seems to be a fair amount of research for "time until a particular event happens", but that doesn't help).

Any hints, standard nomenclature, links, introductory textbook references etc. would be appreciated.

Comment: And if the downvoter could leave a constructive comment, that would be appreciated. It's a serious question, so I don't understand why it gets downvoted.

Comment: Could you expand a little more into these events? Feel free to use references : papers, textbooks etc. for quoting. Perhaps it may be the case that while a "discrete time series" doesn't exist in general, it may have a different kind of name when referenced along with the events you're studying (of course, this may also turn out to not be the case, but I'm trying to be a little more optimistic).